# Insert space after 3 characters in specific column in CSV file

Tags: string, csv, unix, awk, sed

In the file below I want to separate the month part and the date part of the value in the 5th column with a single space character.

Input File:

```
22144842,860998142,1001409110,DLY,Jan4 2016,13:00,17:00
22084015,860902007,29465297,DLY,Jan4 2016,08:00,12:00
22034081,860845334,1001392391,DLY,Jan3 2016,13:00,17:00
22159924,861029758,1001411656,DLY,Jan3 2016,13:00,17:00
22068143,853558982,1001397841,DLY,Jan2 2016,13:00,17:00
```

Required Output File:

```
22144842,860998142,1001409110,DLY,Jan 4 2016,13:00,17:00
22084015,860902007,29465297,DLY,Jan 4 2016,08:00,12:00
22034081,860845334,1001392391,DLY,Jan 3 2016,13:00,17:00
22159924,861029758,1001411656,DLY,Jan 3 2016,13:00,17:00
22068143,853558982,1001397841,DLY,Jan 2 2016,13:00,17:00
```

How could I do this using the AWK language or the sed command ?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{sub(/.../, "& ", $5)}1' File
```

or

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{sub(/[A-Za-z]+/, "& ", $5)}1' File
```

Output:

```
22144842,860998142,1001409110,DLY,Jan 4 2016,13:00,17:00
22084015,860902007,29465297,DLY,Jan 4 2016,08:00,12:00
22034081,860845334,1001392391,DLY,Jan 3 2016,13:00,17:00
22159924,861029758,1001411656,DLY,Jan 3 2016,13:00,17:00
22068143,853558982,1001397841,DLY,Jan 2 2016,13:00,17:00
```

Replace the first `3` characters(`/.../`) of the `5th` field with the same 3 characters (`&`) followed by a `space`. Or, Replace the sequence of characters at the beginning of the `5th` field with the sequence (`&`)followed by `space`.

Comment: Looks good - I would recommend adding a space between the `-v` and `OFS` as some versions of awk won't understand it otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

If you can assume a 3 letter month name in all cases and none of the preceding fields ever contain a comma, you should be able to do this using sed:

```
sed -r 's/([^,]*,){4}[A-Z][a-z]{2}/& /' file
```

The first four fields are described by zero or more characters that are not a comma `[^,]*` followed by a comma. The month name is described by an uppercase letter followed by two lowercase ones. The replacement is everything that is matched `&` with a space added afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/([^,]{0,3})([^,]*)/\1 \2/5' file
```

Split the fifth set of non-delimiters into two and arrange as required.